# Oracle Error while reading from DBMS_METADATA

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to writting stored procedures in Oracle. I want to save the create scripts for materialized view log to a temporary table. Drop those materialized view log, then recreate them using the script stored in the temp table and then drop that table too.
Here is what I have so far, still long ways to go.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE procPrintOutput
IS
  l_stmt VARCHAR2(512) := '';
  --create_table_stmt VARCHAR2(512) := 'create global temporary table temp(matViewLogQuery VARCHAR2(4000))';
  select_stmt VARCHAR2(512) := 'SELECT * from temp';
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1');
    DECLARE
    CURSOR LIST_OF_MVL IS SELECT * FROM USER_BASE_TABLE_MVIEWS;
        BEGIN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2');
            FOR TEST IN LIST_OF_MVL 
          LOOP
            BEGIN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('owner : ' || TEST.OWNER || ' - name : ' || TEST.MASTER);
              l_stmt := 'insert into temp SELECT SYS.DBMS_METADATA.get_dependent_ddl (''MATERIALIZED_VIEW_LOG'', ''|| TEST.MASTER||'', ''|| TEST.OWNER ||'') from dual';
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_stmt);
            END;
          END LOOP;
        END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Done!');

END;
```

The error I am getting when running this is

```
ORA-31608: specified object of type MATERIALIZED_VIEW_LOG not found
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5088
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 7681
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "XXX.PROCPRINTOUTPUT", line 25
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with escaping. This is how it was fixed:

```
l_stmt := 'insert into temp SELECT SYS.DBMS_METADATA.get_dependent_ddl (''MATERIALIZED_VIEW_LOG'', '''||TEST.MASTER||''', '''||TEST.OWNER||''') from dual';
```

Thanks